# for loops with if statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript so please bear with me. I was playing around with for loops and I wrote a loop that is supposed to loop if a variable is less than the specified amount and if the variable is greater than or equal to the specified amount the loop breaks out and console logs that the loop is done but the code is only running and displaying what the for loop condition met is it does not display if the if statement condition is met. Where did I go wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
var ran;
function test(){
        //runs a program that counts a line
        const ran = lineCount;

for (ran;ran < 20;) {
        if (ran >= 20){
                console.log("loop is done")
        }
        console.log("loop is running")
        test()
}
```

Comment: you aren't changing `ran`

Comment: `test` is doing nothing useful: it doesn't return anything and it doesn't modify anything outside its scope. There are two `ran` variables here, and there is one that you didn't define. Quite a lot of issues here. Maybe start with just a loop, and not a function. Build up from small pieces of code until they work, and only then extend to more.

Comment: ```test``` runs a function that counts a line then sets the amount to var ```ran``` then the for loop reads that var and if it's less than 20 it will run the ```test``` function again if it's greater than or equal to 20 it console logs ```loop is done```. To elaborate on the question. @trincot

Comment: Where does `lineCount` come from?

Comment: I was looking for that myself. `LineCount` seems to be for when you have Node.js installed to run javascript...? Myself I always use Vanilla Javascript like: `for (let ran = 0; ran < 20; ran++) {.......`

Comment: ```lineCount``` is the number that the line counter counted and set it to a var ```ran```. @evolutionxbox

Comment: *"`test` runs a function that counts a line then sets the amount to var `ran`"*: yes, and my point is that no-one is doing anything with *that* `ran` (it is not the same variable as the other `ran`), and so that result is going to oblivion as soon as `test` completes.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to decipher what you are trying to do. But I mainly changed:

- Change from `const ran` to `let ran`.
- Use a conventional setup for for-loop which includes, variable declaration and variable increment
- Removed recursively

```js
function test() {
    for (let ran = lineCount; ran < 20; ran++) {
        if (ran >= 20) {
            console.log("loop is done");
        }
        console.log("loop is running");
    }
}
```

Comment: ```test``` is supposed to be a function that counts the number of lines in a text file and sets the counted amount to a var ```ran``` hence ```const ran = lineCount```. The for loop should re-run ```test``` if  ```ran``` is less than 20 and if it is greater than or equal to 20 ```console.log("loop is done");```. @Jason Kim